# Drupal Forms - Setting a Default Value

Tags: drupal, drupal-webform

I am using the webform module for Drupal 6 and would like to set a default value for the confirmation message of the webform whenever it is created.  Would I have to create my own module to set this form value whenever a user creates a new webform?  Or would I have to implement a special hook to look for when a webform is created?

Comment: Are you talking about whenever a user actually creates a new webform, or when a user fills out an already created webform?

Comment: When a user creates a new webform.

Comment: Right now I'm currently going the module route, writing a custom module that implements hook_form_alter and says if($form_id == 'webform_node_form') set the default value of the confirmation message.  Don't know if it'll work though still banging away on it now.

Comment: Still no luck with hook_form_alter  trying all sorts of variations of it.  trying function named webform_node_form_form_alter

Comment: Gotten this far now.

function customMod_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id){
 
 if($form_id == 'webform_node_form'){
  $node = $form['#node'];
  $webform = $node->webform;

  $node->webform['confirmation'] = "test test test";

The hook is executing and the array value is being set, but it still isn't appearing in the text field of the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You going to want to use the following:

```
customMod_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id){ 
  if($form_id == 'webform_node_form'){ 
    $form['id_of_conf_message_field']['#default_value'] = 'BLAH BLAH'
  }
}
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, custom module and hook_form_alter... Thanks!

Comment: But how do i do this in case of hidden field in web forms? its doesnt have id\

Comment: This solution did not work for me however [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12194243/967168) did work.

Answer (score 1):

@esafwan .. I'm not sure whether this shall help in your case with the hidden fields issue but
I found this link for default variable values http://drupal.org/node/296453 
so I was able to create a hidden field in my already existent webform with default value %request[key] and worked perfectly ..